# Updating specific <div> to update chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, charts

I am plotting chart in the `aspx page`. The chart is been placed in a `<div>`. I need to update the only specific `<div>` so that I can get the `chart`updated every 1 second without refreshing entire page.

Below is my code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" Namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

       <div id="chart">
    <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="455px" Width="473px" BackColor="DarkGray" BackGradientStyle="Center" BackHatchStyle="BackwardDiagonal" BackImageTransparentColor="0, 192, 192">
        <Series>
            <asp:Series Name="Series1" ChartType="FastPoint" XValueMember="dt" YValueMembers="Id" XValueType="DateTime"></asp:Series>
        </Series>
        <ChartAreas>
            <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
        </ChartAreas>
    </asp:Chart>



<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:MyConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT top(100) [dt], [Id] FROM [Test4] order by Id desc"></asp:SqlDataSource>

    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put your chart inside an `updatepanel` and then refresh update panel in the specific time intervals using `timer` control

These links may help you

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295400.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1492639.aspx

**Edit**

The better way is to use jquery ajax calls. The general idea of its implementation would be

1. Create a user control(.ascx file) which will contain your chart and logic to load it.
2. Define a method in any of the cs file which will create the instance of this user control(using `Page.LoadControl` method) and then call some of its method to load it and return the panel or placeholder of it, from where you can generate html using `RenderControl` method and this html will be shown to your `div`
3. This method can be called through jquery in the specific intervals

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET is a server side language, meaning the sqldatasource control will only execute server side when the page is first generated.

You can work with this by either putting the chart inside an `<iframe>` tag and refreshing that frame every second, or you can try to get complicated and write a web api that responds to requests with JSON data, and use AJAX to update the div.

MVC 4 has a pretty robust web api baked in, but if you didn't start from an MVC 4 project template then you're probably better off just making a single aspx page that handles your JSON outputs based on parameters.